# Why the quotient map not always open map?

Tags: general-topology

I really don't understand because the quotient map of topological spaces not always open ?

Let (X, $\tau$) be a topological space and ~ an equivalence relation on X. Consider the quotient map q: X $\rightarrow$ X/~ given by q(x) = [x].

Let U $\in \tau$. Then, q$^{-1}(q(U))$ = q$^{-1}(\cup_{u \in U}[u])$ = $\cup_{u \in U} q^{-1}([u])$ = U $\in \tau$.

Therefore, q(U) is open in $\tau$X/~

Comment: Map the entire space to a single point.

Comment: @JohnDouma.  Your map is open.

Comment: Your computation $q^{-1} q U = U$ is wrong. In general $U \subsetneqq q^{-1} q U$.

Comment: I bet you can easily construct an equivalence relation and a subset $U$ that is a counterexample to the equation $\cup_{u \in U} q^{-1}([u]) = U$.

Comment: @LeeMosher and others, thanks for comments. Let $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology and define x ~ 0 for every x $\in$ (-$\infty$, 0] and x ~1 for every x $\in$ (0, $\infty$). Define q: $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$/~ and note that q$^{-1}(q(-\infty, 0))$ = (-$\infty$,0] that does not belong the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example goes from a three-point space to a two-point space.

Let $X$ be $\{1,2,3\}$ with the topology $\{\{\},\{1\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ and the equivalence relation $\sim$ identifying $1$ with $2$. Then, $\{1\}$ is open in $X$, but $q(\{1\})=\{\{1,2\}\}$ is not open in $X/\sim$, because $q^{-1}(\{\{1,2\}\})=\{1,2\}$ is not open in $X$.